# Autohotkey Script won't send keystrokes in Lotus notes

Tags: autohotkey, lotus-notes

An autohotkey script I've written to write out emails for me in IBM lotus notes works fine for me, but when I share the script to my other coworkers to use, keystrokes won't send on their IBM Lotus notes. The script will work when I use it in their microsoft word, however, they won't work on IBM Lotus notes. Is there a setting on Lotus notes to allow keystroke macros to be sent? Is there a syntax in autohotkey that can allow it to bypass restrictions?

I've added the following in front of my script with hashtags and still no luck:
InstallKeybdHook, UseHook On, NoEnv, Warn

I can't run scripts on administrator as a corporate firewall is blocking our access

I've tried changing SendInput to SendPlay and SendEvent

```
^d::
row := 2 
wbk := 
ComObjGet("C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\target\excelfile.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1")

email := wbk.Cells(row, 3).Value
companyname := wbk.Cells(row, 1).Value
personname := wbk.Cells(row, 2).Value
subject := wbk.Cells(2, 1).Value
emailpart := wbk.Cells(2, 3).Value

;Enter sender name
SendInput, % email

;Enter subject
Send, {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}
SendInput, % subject
SendInput, % companyname
Send, {Tab}

;Enter email
Send, Hi{Space}
SendInput, % personname
Send, ,{Enter}{Enter}
SendInput, % emailpart 
Send, {Enter}

row++
Return
```

Comment: I use autothotkey in Notes on a daily basis without any problems using Send, however I'm not fetching values from a spreadsheet.  I certainly don't know of any restriction in Notes to prevent keystrokes being sent, so I suspect your problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: @PhilMJones Thanks for the help, I don't believe the issue lies in fetching the values from the spread sheet, it works on microsoft word and other programs, as well as my work computer. Perhaps your path for ComObjGet is off?

Comment: To help narrow down the issue, does a simple `Send, Hello World` to the body of the message work? (i.e. is it an issue with the keys sending to Notes or with something else?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Control commands?

ControlSend , Control, Keys, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText

GuiControl, SubCommand, ControlID , Value

When I use the basic Send command I usually use the BlockInput On before the Send and BlockInput Off right after.

Be careful with BlockInput. Make sure your code will not get get stuck in a loop after a Block Input On command.